# Extract coordinates from an EPS file to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, eps, illustrator, bezier

Apologies in advance if the question is off topic. I believe it is proper of TeX and LaTeX Stack Exchange, as it is about TikZ, after all, but if I am mistaken, please redirect me to the proper forum.

I have created a simple image, made only of Bézier's curves with Adobe Illustrator which I can save as PDF or EPS and insert in the latex document using `graphicx` and the instruction `\includegraphics`. However, I need to replicate it in TikZ in order to apply transformations on it. Is there any way to get the coordinates of the image from the EPS/PDF file (or any other that Illustrator can export in)? Or do I need to redo the image 'ex novo' in TikZ?

Thank you for any help you can provide: the image is quite complex and I don't think I would be able to do it straight on TikZ, without using a graphic interface.

Comment: Normally TeX could not extract info from included EPS/PDF, but you can apply transformation on the included image in (La)TeX, if that is the only needed operation. So, which transformation(s) do you want to apply?

Comment: Basically it is a simple letter drawn with illustrator and I need to show all the points (anchor points and handles) for a presentation on Bézier's curves. So what I need to do is to highlight all the point (with different colours) and then I want to scale, rotate and translate the letter to show the invariance of the Bézier's curves under these transformations

Comment: The application pstoedit allows to export ps and epsilon files to asy or mps files. It is easy tonedit these files.